# Change Entry widget value from other function

Tags: python-3.x, class, tkinter

I am quite new in programming with tkinter , especially with classes. How can I make a button that runs function from the same class and changes entry widget. In my code i want to change entry1 whenever button1 is clicked and filepath function runs.

thank you for your help.

```
Class Example(Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def filepath():
        filename = fd.askopenfilename()
        entry1.delete(0,END)
        entry1.insert(0,filename)

    def initUI(self):

        self.master.title("EFEKTYWNOŚĆ APP")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

        cd = (os.getcwd())

        frame1 = Frame(self)
        frame1.pack(side = LEFT)

        lbl1 = Label(frame1, 
                     text="...",
                     wraplength = 250 )
        lbl1.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)

        path = os.path.join(cd, 'ico', '...')
        photo = PhotoImage(file = path)
        cphoto = photo.subsample(4,4)
        button1  = Button(frame1,
                          text='WYBIERZ PLIK',
                          image = cphoto,
                          compound = LEFT, 
                          command = Example.filepath)
        button1.image = cphoto
        button1.pack(side=LEFT, fill = Y, padx=5, pady=5)

        entry1 = Entry(frame1)
        entry1.pack(side=LEFT, fill = Y, padx=5, pady=5)
```

Comment: If you want entry1 to be a class atribute instead of a local variable of initUI method, you need to use it as self.entry1. Same with other variables. It's fine if you don't need to access them outside of the class method they were introduced in, as the data itself wont be removed, just its association with the name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some minor things needed to be fixed in your code. I have added a working sample with comments below.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog as fd
import os

class Example(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master,**kwargs): #have your Frame accept parameters like how a normal frame should
        super().__init__(master,**kwargs)
        self.master = master #set master as an attribute so you can access it later
        self.initUI()

    def filepath(self): #add self to make the method an instance method
        filename = fd.askopenfilename()
        self.entry1.delete(0, END) #use self when referring to an instance attribute
        self.entry1.insert(0, filename)


    def initUI(self):
        self.master.title("EFEKTYWNOŚĆ APP")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

        cd = (os.getcwd())

        frame1 = Frame(self)
        frame1.pack(side=LEFT)

        lbl1 = Label(frame1,
                     text="...",
                     wraplength=250)
        lbl1.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)

        path = os.path.join(cd, 'ico', '...')
        photo = PhotoImage(file=path)
        cphoto = photo.subsample(4, 4)
        button1 = Button(frame1,
                         text='WYBIERZ PLIK',
                         image=cphoto,
                         compound=LEFT,
                         command=self.filepath) #refer to instance methods by self.your_method
        button1.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.entry1 = Entry(frame1) #add self to make it an instance attribute
        self.entry1.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y, padx=5, pady=5) #you will then need to use self.entry1 within your class instance

root = Tk()
Example(root)
root.mainloop()
```